# Data is not displayed in TableView

Tags: c++, qt, view, model, qml

I try to build simple TableView with model from C++. My table has as many rows and columns, as return rowCount and columnCount method. This means, model is 'connected' with view, but in each cell does not display the message: 'Some data'

here is my code:

```
class PlaylistModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    PlaylistModel(QObject *parent=0): QAbstractTableModel(parent), rows(0){}

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex & /*parent*/) const
    {
        return 5;
    }
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex & /*parent*/) const
    {
        return 3;
    }
    QModelIndex index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const {
         return createIndex(row, column);
    }
    QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex &child) const {
         return child.parent();
    }
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const{
        if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
             {
               return QString("Some data");
             }
        return QVariant();
    }
(...)
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
PlaylistModel plModel(0);
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myModel", &plModel);
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));
```

and qml

```
TableView {
                id: trackList
                width: 100; height: 100
                model: myModel
                TableViewColumn { role: "id"; title: "Id"; width: 30 }
                TableViewColumn { role: "name"; title: "Name"; width: 100}
                TableViewColumn { role: "duration"; title: "Duration"; width: 20 }

            }
```

Where I make a mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Short answer

Because your QML is not asking for `Qt::DisplayRole`. Change your `TableVievColumn` to

```
TableViewColumn { role: "display"; title: "xxx"; width: 20 }
```

The QML is now asking for `Qt::DisplayRole`, and "Some data" is shown in this column.

### Long answer

QML is asking for three user-defined roles: "id", "name", and "duration". However, the three roles are not bulit-in roles. Therefore you need to implement the three roles in your model class.

First, you should provide a set of roles to the model. The model returns data to views using `QAbstractItemModel::data` function. The type of `role` is int, we can write an enum in the model class:

```
class PlaylistModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum MyTableRoles 
    {
        IdRole = Qt::UserRole + 1,
        NameRole,
        DurationRole
    }
    //...
};
```

Now, in the `data` function, returns the corresponding value any time the view is asking:

```
QVariant PlaylistModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid()){return QVariant();}

    switch(role)
    {
    case IdRole:
        return GetIdFromMyTable(index);
    case NameRole:
        return GetNameFromMyTable(index);
    case DurationRole:
        return GetDurationFromMyTable(index);
    }
    //...
    return QVariant();
}
```

Next, provide a string-to-int mapping for each role. The `role` in the model is in type of int, however in the QML the `role` is type of string. (see the role property in `TableViewColumn`.) Therefore we should provide a string-to-int mapping for each role so the QML can correctly asking for the required data. The mapping should be provided in `QAbstractItemModel::roleNames()`:

```
QHash<int, QByteArray> PlaylistModel::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNameMap;
    roleNameMap[IdRole] = "id";
    roleNameMap[NameRole] = "name";
    roleNameMap[DurationRole] = "duration";

    return roleNameMap;
}
```

Finally your table in QML now can display the things you want.

### Some references

When subclassing [QAbstractTableModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstracttablemodel.html#subclassing),

> you must implement rowCount(), columnCount(), and data(). Default implementations of the index() and parent() functions are provided by QAbstractTableModel.

When using [C++ models in QML](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html#qabstractitemmodel),

> The roles of a QAbstractItemModel subclass can be exposed to QML by reimplementing QAbstractItemModel::roleNames().

And if you do not reimplement the `roleNames` function, you can use only the default roles declared in [QAbstractItemModel::roleNames](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#roleNames). And this is the reason why the short answer works.

Comment: Using QWidget it also solve the problem: data function need to return invalid QVariant if the role is not DisplayRole

Answer (score 0):

You did not implemented `index` method.

According to documentation,

> When subclassing QAbstractItemModel, at the very least you must
>   implement **index()**, parent(), rowCount(), columnCount(), and data().
>   These functions are used in all read-only models, and form the basis
>   of editable models.

in other words, You have to implement your own low-level item management, AbstractItemModel will not do it for you. You should create indexes with `createIndex` and destroy them when nesessary etc.

If you don't want to play these games and just want to implement your own quick&dirty model, consider subclassing QStandardItemModel.

Comment: My code work when I use QTableView widget but don't work when I use qml TableView. As you suggested I add two method but still I don't get 'Some data' message in each cell. I editted my code. Check this method please.

Comment: @iwaszek12 it seems to be all OK. Maybe this is QML problems? Maybe there are some flags&roles issues? Try to: a) remove `if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)` condition and return "some data" for ANY role. b) change it into `if (role == Qt::DisplayRole || role == Qt::EditRole)` and return not `QVariant()`, but QAbstractItemModel::data(index, ...) in else.